# How to find values missing from a sequence?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, gaps-and-islands

I want to find rows missing from a sequence of values in my table. For example, in this picture `documentno` `'YD4BC2006008'` is missing.

I want to find the missing lines via `c_order_id` and `documentno`.

I tried this but it didn't return the expected result:

```
select * from
(SELECT distinct c_order_id, documentno,cast(right(documentno,3) as integer) as no
FROM adempiere.c_order
ORDER BY documentno, c_order_id) as f
```

[image]

In this example  many rows missing: from `'DGPOS2003030'` to `'DGPOS2003068'`.

How do I write a query to retrieve them?

[image]

Comment: All rows have same format, i want to get missing rows

Comment: I tried code  select * from
(SELECT distinct c_order_id, documentno,cast(right(documentno,3) as integer) as no
FROM adempiere.c_order
ORDER BY documentno, c_order_id) as f but it is not finich

Comment: c_order_id is  primary key

Comment: Does the record YD4BC2006008 exist, or are you trying to find the records that don't exist? If that's what you're after, then Colin's answer below should serve.

Comment: i want to find record that existed but was deleted like YD4BC2006008 or DGPOS2003030, DGPOS2003031,DGPOS2003032.......DGPOS2003068 for example

Comment: How do you identify missing numbers, is it just the last 7 digits we need to look at or can the alphabetical characters also be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more dynamic approach would be
, getting the lowest Number and the highest and building the m missing from there.

If you don't have a leading 2 like in the example 2006004 you need to pad the generated part

> ```
> CREATE TABLE documents (
>   "order_id" VARCHAR(22),
>   "documentno" VARCHAR(12)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO documents
>   ("order_id", "documentno")
> VALUES
>   ('100001110', 'VD4BC2006004'),
>   ('100001114' ,'VD4BC2006005'),
>   ('100001135' ,'YD4BC2006006'),
>   ('100001166' ,'YD4BC2006007'),
>   ('100001215' ,'YD4BC2006009'),
>   ('100001256' ,'YD4BC2006010'),
>   ('100001289' ,'YD4BC2006011'),
>   ('100001332' ,'VD4BC2006013'),
>   ('100001334' ,'VD4BC2006014'),
>   ('100001432' ,'VD4BC2006015'),
>   ('100000616' ,'DGP0S2003028'),
>   ('100000617' ,'DGP0S2003029'),
>   ('100001034' ,'DGP0S2003069');
> ```

> ```
> WITH cte as (
> SELECT LEFT("documentno",5) lpart , MIN(RIGHT("documentno",7)) minpart, MaX(RIGHT("documentno",7)) maxpart FROM documents
> groUP BY LEFT("documentno",5))
> sELECT lpart || generate_series(minpart::INTEGER, maxpart::INTEGER) as mdocumentno FROM cte
> except
> select documentno from documents
> ORDER bY mdocumentno;
> ```
>
> ```
> | mdocumentno  |
> | :----------- |
> | DGP0S2003030 |
> | DGP0S2003031 |
> | DGP0S2003032 |
> | DGP0S2003033 |
> | DGP0S2003034 |
> | DGP0S2003035 |
> | DGP0S2003036 |
> | DGP0S2003037 |
> | DGP0S2003038 |
> | DGP0S2003039 |
> | DGP0S2003040 |
> | DGP0S2003041 |
> | DGP0S2003042 |
> | DGP0S2003043 |
> | DGP0S2003044 |
> | DGP0S2003045 |
> | DGP0S2003046 |
> | DGP0S2003047 |
> | DGP0S2003048 |
> | DGP0S2003049 |
> | DGP0S2003050 |
> | DGP0S2003051 |
> | DGP0S2003052 |
> | DGP0S2003053 |
> | DGP0S2003054 |
> | DGP0S2003055 |
> | DGP0S2003056 |
> | DGP0S2003057 |
> | DGP0S2003058 |
> | DGP0S2003059 |
> | DGP0S2003060 |
> | DGP0S2003061 |
> | DGP0S2003062 |
> | DGP0S2003063 |
> | DGP0S2003064 |
> | DGP0S2003065 |
> | DGP0S2003066 |
> | DGP0S2003067 |
> | DGP0S2003068 |
> | VD4BC2006006 |
> | VD4BC2006007 |
> | VD4BC2006008 |
> | VD4BC2006009 |
> | VD4BC2006010 |
> | VD4BC2006011 |
> | VD4BC2006012 |
> | YD4BC2006008 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c70d8ffa2d850c5e26b821f9cd71b4df)*

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to generate a list of all potential `documentno`s and remove from that all the ones that exist:

```
select 'YD4BC' || generate_series(2006004, 2006015) as missing_documentno
except
select documentno from documents;
```